# Android: Json data is not retrieving from TMdb API host

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json

I'm building movie app using tmdb API. I'm using retrofit to fetch the data. I have verified my api-key working perfectly fine. But data from TMDb is not fetching.

**Here is my API Interface**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface MoviesAPI {

@GET("/movie/popular")
 Call<MovieBean> getPopular(@Query("apikey")String key);
}
```

**Retrofit builder method**

```
public void getPopularMovies() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
   final String api_key = getString(R.string.tmdb_api_key);
   final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    MoviesAPI service = retrofit.create(MoviesAPI.class);
    Call<MovieBean> call = service.getPopular(api_key);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieBean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieBean> call, Response<MovieBean> response) {
            Log.d("movietest", "onResponse() tmdb, response_success? -" + response.isSuccessful());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieBean> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have another Interface and retrofit builder class uses OMdb API works perfectly fine
**Below is OMDb API Interface**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface MoviesAPI2 {
   @GET("/")
   public Call<MovieBean2> getInfo(@Query("apikey")String omdbkey, 
             @Query("t")String movName,@Query("plot") String plot);
}
```

And retrofit class

```
 private static Retrofit obj = null;
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?";

public static Retrofit getInstance(){
    //Interceptor httpLogging = new
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    if(obj==null){
        obj = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return obj;
}

 public void search_movie() {


         final String PLOT = "full";
        Log.d("movietest", "entered input " + title);
        // I get title from searchView
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitBuilder.getInstance();
        MoviesAPI2 service = retrofit.create(MoviesAPI2.class);
        Call<MovieBean2> call = service.getInfo(getString(R.string.omdb_api_key), title,PLOT);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieBean2>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieBean2> call, Response<MovieBean2> response) {
                Log.d("movietest", "onResponse(),success" + response.isSuccessful());
                mBean = response.body();

                tvTit.setText(mBean.getTitle());
                tvDesc.setText(mBean.getPlot());
                tvactors.setText(mBean.getActors());
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mBean.getPoster()).into(imagView);
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mBean.getPoster()).into(imgView);
                Log.d("movietest", "onResponse(), bean 2=" + mBean);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieBean2> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not fetch.Please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me to fix this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API interface should look like this:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface MoviesAPI {

@GET("3/movie/popular")
    Call<MovieBean> getPopular(@Query("api_key") String key);
}
```

Note that the query parameter is `api_key` & not `apikey`.

`@GET` method needs to be declared like this **everything excluding** `BASE_URL` which will be:

```
final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not start your url with "/" instead put it in your base url

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface MoviesAPI {

@GET("movie/popular")
 Call<MovieBean> getPopular(@Query("apikey")String key);
}
```

above change makes the perfect url for you,try it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I corrected the code as u suggested but still couldn't fetch the data. Response shows false.

Answer (score 0):

I did it you can check my app on github -- shivam141296/moviesapi.
base_url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

@GET("movie/popular")
    Call getPopular(@Query("api_key") String apikey);